# How can I exclude class in Android projects with Kotlin

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

When I create an Android Project with Java only, these code below works well:

```
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                exclude '**/ExcludeClass.java'
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I import Kotlin support for Android, it is complete failure. This class wasn't removed by gradle(both of these class are not removed):

```
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                exclude '**/TestExcludeClass.java'
            }

            kotlin {
                exclude '**/TestExcludeKotlinClass.kt'
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how to exclude class in an Android project with Kotlin?

Comment: before this `{` instead of `kotlin` change to `java` and  `exclude '**/*.kt'` exclude a .kt file, `exclude '**/myKotlin/*.kt'` exclude .kt files in myKotlin directory.

Comment: My mistake. I have changed the question. Thanks for adv but it's not work for me.

Comment: you need to add srcDir 'src' above the exclude refer this [exclude certain java files from being compiled](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-exclude-certain-java-files-from-being-compiled/5287)

Comment: After I add the srcDir 'src' in both closure, it works for java file but not kotlin file. Too weird.

Comment: for kotlin refer this [exclude kotlin files from compiling with gradle](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-exclude-kotlin-files-from-compiling-with-gradle/30365)

Comment: Finally it works, thanks a lot.

Comment: Nothing works from what was suggested, anything changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude all Kotlin files in a folder you can use the `kotlin` block in `main` `sourceSets` in your Gradle file like this:

```
android {
    ...

    sourceSets {
        main {
            kotlin {
                exclude '**/exclude/*.kt'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example the name of the folder to exclude is `exclude` and all of the Kotlin files in it are excluded from the final build.